# Pack files (.py, .dll)

Tags: python, c++, dll, mfc, exe

I'm trying to create a simple game using C++ with Python embedding. The python code is embedded in my C++ code. I used Python/C API for this. Main programm wrote on MFC. My purpose, that programm will be run on computer, where not installed Python. For this I put these files in my .exe directory:

```
        python27.dll
        Python27\
            DLLs\ (contents of DLLs folder)
            Lib\ (contents of Lib folder)
```

But I want to put these files in my .exe. It's possible? May be I can link my programm with Python together to create single .exe Read many posts, but didn't find solution...
P.S. About py2exe and etc. I know, but it is for create .exe from "clean" Python programm.

Comment: The only way to have the python code embedded in your exe is if the python codes comes as a static lib, which looks unlikely from the directory layout you have described.

Comment: @user1793036 and can you tell some more details how I can compile Python in a static lib?